# ZeroMQ - Handling slow receivers without dropping

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system

I have an architecture where I have a **`ROUTER`** socket and multiple **`DEALER`** sockets.

Some `DEALER` sockets will only send data, some will only receive data and others can do a mixture of both.

I have a scenario, where I have one `DEALER` socket, that is sending data at an extremely fast rate. This data is received by another `DEALER`, that will process this as fast as it can. The send rate is always going to be higher than the receive.

In my current setup the `ZMQ_SNDHWM` on my **`ROUTER`** socket gets hit for the receive client and will silently drop messages. I do not want this to be the case.

What is the best way to do so as to deal with this scenario?

I have looked at `DEALER->DEALER` on a different port, but this could be hard to maintain, depending on the number of sessions that are created I could potentially have to have one port per session.

The other way I can think of solving this is to do some pipe-lining in which the receiving `DEALER` socket will tell the sender when it is ready to receive but this seems to add a lot of complication to the overall protocol and a lot more state management. It also seems to defeat the ability to be able to naturally block on `DEALER` sockets which is really what I need in this case; the `DEALER` sockets will never have to communicate with any other socket.

Answer (score 2):

### Do not rely on blocking, the less on uncontrolled use of resources

In [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) there is not much space for optimistic beliefs and expectations. In many posts I advocate, where possible, not to rely on blocking states, as your code gets out-of-control and you cannot do anything about leaving such a state, but pray for a message to come any time soon, if ever.

Rather bear the responsibility, end-to-end, which in [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) means that you need to also design strategies how to survive a "remote" death and similar situations, that are outside of the range of your-domain-of-control, but which your code design has no right to abstract from.

---

### Even if not willing to, an explicit flow-management is the way to go

Late 90-ies have demonstrated many flow-control strategies for distributed systems, so this is definitely not a new field.

Increasing the box-of-worm size does not help to manage the un-controlled / un-managed flow of events. While **`ZMQ_???HMW`** + **`ZMQ_???BUF`** may help somehow tweak non-brutal cases, where having a bit more space may temporarily postpone the principal weakness of un-controlled message-flows, yet the problem is like remaining stand still with closed eyes right in the middle of the cross-fire shooting. Such agent may survive, but it's survival is not a result of it's design cleverness, but just an accidental luck.

Token-passing seems to be the cheapest way how to throttle the flow so as to remain acceptable / process-able on the slowest node. Increasing such a node-processing performance may be done with a use of a static, an incrementally expanded or a fully adaptive pooling-proxy, so even this known bottleneck remains manageable and under your design-control.

The highest layer of robustness is in making your [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system)'s design resilient to spurious bursts of events ( be it messages or `.connect()` attempts ). So, independently of selecting the building blocks, designer has also the responsibility to design in all the survival-strategies. Not doing this leaves your system vulnerable to capacity-directed vector of attack or other sort of unhandled exploits of these kinds of known weakness vulnerabilites.